# Using NRF24L01 as transmitter and receiver (transceiver)

Tags: c++, nrf24l01+

I am using the NRF24L01 module to communicate between multiple Arduinos. For this example I will have a master transmiter (tx) Arduino and a salve receiver (rx) Arduino to illustrative better my problem.

**Master (Tx) code:**

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(9, 10); // NRF24L01 used SPI pins + Pin 9 and 10 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    radio.begin();               
    radio.openWritingPipe(27);
    radio.stopListening();
}

void loop() {
    char buf[32];
    buf[0] = 123;

    auto res = radio.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (res) {
        Serial.println("worked");
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("** error **");
        delay(1000);
    }
       
    delay(700); // wait 700 ms

}
```

**Slave (Rx) Code**

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>

RF24 radio(9, 10); // NRF24L01 used SPI pins + Pin 9 and 10 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    radio.begin();               
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, 27);
    radio.startListening();
}

void codeThatMakesMasterAckStopWorking()
{
    // Code that will be changed
}

void loop() {
    
    if (radio.available()) {
       char buf[32];          
       radio.read(buf, 32);
       Serial.println("received data");
       codeThatMakesMasterAckStopWorking();
       
    }

}
```

If I execute this code it works great just as it is. The master (tx) always gets an acknowledgment every time it sends data. Also the range of the NRF24L01 works great. **The problem occurs when the slave sends data becoming a transmitter instead of a receiver**. In other words if I replace the method `codeThatMakesMasterAckStopWorking` with:

```
void codeThatMakesMasterAckStopWorking()
{
    radio.stopListening();
    radio.openWritingPipe(1234); // send to some other node that is not master
    char buf[32];
    radio.write(buf, 32);
    radio.startListening();
}
```

The master (Tx) is able to send the data because the slave prints the message `"received data"` but without acknowledgment. The master keeps printing `** error **` even though the slave is receiving the data. I been doing a lot of tests and this are my findings:

```
// does not work (master stops receiving acknowledgment and prints '** error **')
void codeThatMakesMasterAckStopWorking()
{
    radio.stopListening();
    delay(200);
    radio.startListening();
}


// works (master receives acknowledgment and prints 'worked')
void codeThatMakesMasterAckStopWorking()
{
    radio.stopListening();
    delay(10);
    radio.startListening();
}
```

There are times when I want my slave arduino to stop listening and transmit a message to another arduino. When it sends a message to a different arduino the master does not receive an acknowledgment anymore even though the slave is listening again. Why could this be?

Comment: google `arduino rf24mesh`

Comment: Does increasing the delay from 700 to, say, 2000 have any effect? PS what does `sleep` do. I don't think that's part the standard Arduino functions.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write delay @garben

Comment: Try using the nRFLite library.